# Firebase Data Structuring for a Multi-Channel News Feed App

Tags: firebase

We are building a Realtime Social News Feed app for iOS and Android using Parse and Firebase. Parse is used for User Management and Push Notifications.

**Requirements**:

There will be multiple news channels based on the categorised by interest, say Food, Technology, Travel, Finance, Business, etc..

Channel Managers have the ability to publish a text/picture/video/audio post to the Channel News Feed.
Users can follow one or many channels and there will get a unified news feed of the posts from the channels they are following in reverse chronological order.
They can favourite/like some of the posts.

We are looking at a way to group the feed from all the Channels the user has followed and deliver it to the user's device. Pubnub has a way to achieve this using Channel Groups (https://www.pubnub.com/products/stream-controller/)

Since we are looking at scaling upto a million devices that install the app,  I need help on identifying the right Data Model in Firebase to achieve this.

**Here is how I modelled it now:**

Channels tree will store the list of Channels along with PostsFeed which will contain the Post IDs associated with the channel . This will help when we need to display the feed for a particular Channel, we only need to look in a single place.

The actual Posts will be in Posts tree which is also the global list of all Posts.

Likes are stored against each post as an array.

```
            {
                "Channels": {
                    "-JwGRWPudmaRwT8dpx40": {
                        "channelId": "RrHhZCXQkL",
                        "channelName": "C1",
                        "PostsFeed": {
                            "-JwGRWPudmaRwT8dpx79": {
                                "date": "2015-08-09T07:52:12.GMT"
                            },
                            "-JwGRiLa2Nz1vfhWNgFa": {
                                "date": "2015-08-09T07:52:50.GMT"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "-JwGRWPudmaRwT8dpx50": {
                        "channelId": "IxyMMJdPjs",
                        "channelName": "C2",
                        "PostsFeed": {
                            "-JwGReVetAxVWWJkc3L4": {
                                "date": "2015-08-09T07:52:50.GMT"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "-JwGRWPudmaRwT8dpx60": {
                        "channelId": "ePuAN4qAj7",
                        "channelName": "C3",
                        "PostsFeed": {
                            "-JwGRlNNQkefrr953PgX": {
                                "date": "2015-08-09T07:53:18.GMT"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Posts": {
                    "-JwGRWPudmaRwT8dpx79": {
                        "audio": "",
                        "audio_duration": 0,
                        "channelId": "RrHhZCXQkL",
                        "channelName": "C1",
                        "channelPicture": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/channel/7636019341/picture.jpg",
                        "channelThumbnail": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/channel/7636019341/thumbnail.jpg",
                        "date": "2015-08-09T07: 52: 12.GMT",
                        "interval": 1439106732.326777,
                        "key": "-JwGRWPudmaRwT8dpx79",
                        "likes": [
                            "sEIXov9ebP"
                        ],
                        "name": "PowerUser",
                        "picture": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/picture/2376019341/picture.jpg",
                        "picture_height": 424,
                        "picture_width": 638,
                        "text": "[Picturepost ]",
                        "thumbnail": "",
                        "type": "picture",
                        "userId": "fgzoFVtexv",
                        "video": "",
                        "video_duration": 0
                    },
                    "-JwGReVetAxVWWJkc3L4": {
                        "audio": "",
                        "audio_duration": 0,
                        "channelId": "IxyMMJdPjs",
                        "channelName": "C2",
                        "channelPicture": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/channel/7066019341/picture.jpg",
                        "channelThumbnail": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/channel/7066019341/thumbnail.jpg",
                        "date": "2015-08-09T07: 52: 50.GMT",
                        "interval": 1439106770.490803,
                        "key": "-JwGReVetAxVWWJkc3L4",
                        "likes": [
                            "sEIXov9ebP"
                        ],
                        "name": "PowerUser",
                        "picture": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/picture/0776019341/picture.jpg",
                        "picture_height": 636,
                        "picture_width": 638,
                        "text": "[ Picturepost]",
                        "thumbnail": "",
                        "type": "picture",
                        "userId": "fgzoFVtexv",
                        "video": "",
                        "video_duration": 0
                    },
                    "-JwGRiLa2Nz1vfhWNgFa": {
                        "audio": "",
                        "audio_duration": 0,
                        "channelId": "ePuAN4qAj7",
                        "channelName": "C1",
                        "channelPicture": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/channel/8756019341/picture.jpg",
                        "channelThumbnail": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/channel/8756019341/thumbnail.jpg",
                        "date": "2015-08-09T07: 53: 04.GMT",
                        "interval": 1439106784.834503,
                        "key": "-JwGRiLa2Nz1vfhWNgFa",
                        "likes": [
                            "sEIXov9ebP"
                        ],
                        "name": "PowerUser",
                        "picture": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/picture/4876019341/picture.jpg",
                        "picture_height": 638,
                        "picture_width": 638,
                        "text": "[Picturepost]]",
                        "thumbnail": "",
                        "type": "picture",
                        "userId": "fgzoFVtexv",
                        "video": "",
                        "video_duration": 0
                    },
                    "-JwGRlNNQkefrr953PgX": {
                        "audio": "",
                        "audio_duration": 0,
                        "channelId": "ePuAN4qAj7",
                        "channelName": "C3",
                        "channelPicture": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/channel/8756019341/picture.jpg",
                        "channelThumbnail": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/channel/8756019341/thumbnail.jpg",
                        "date": "2015-08-09T07: 53: 18.GMT",
                        "interval": 1439106798.653415,
                        "key": "-JwGRlNNQkefrr953PgX",
                        "likes": [
                            "sEIXov9ebP"
                        ],
                        "name": "PowerUser",
                        "picture": "https: //a.cloudfront.net/fgzoFVtexv/picture/8976019341/picture.jpg",
                        "picture_height": 304,
                        "picture_width": 638,
                        "text": "[Picturepost]",
                        "thumbnail": "",
                        "type": "picture",
                        "userId": "fgzoFVtexv",
                        "video": "",
                        "video_duration": 0
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: The requirements look akin to the Firebase Firefeed example, so you might want to look there for inspiration: https://firefeed.io/. You'll see that Firefeed keeps a list of all messages to show *to* each user. This has the advantage that each user only has to read one location to get their messages, at the cost of having to write each update to multiple locations. Whether this is the right trade-off for you app, only you can tell.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the update. The current design is inspired by firefeed.io example. We have a running app with it with 200 users. Since we plan to scale it up to more users, I am evaluating at different approaches. If User has to read only one location to get their messages, I'm afraid that will be a huge thing to deal with when we hit half a million users. Is there a way in firebase where we can group data from multiple streams/nodes onto a single connection ? (something like channel grouping in Pubnub) ?

Comment: Nope. Firebase is a state synchronization paradigm, not a message passing paradigm. You can build message passing on top of Firebase, just define your own `channels` nodes. Unrelated: if you expect a million users each to monitor multiple (say 10) channels, you'll have 1M * 10 listeners. That's quite a lot. If you fan out the data with a "node for each user", you'll have "only" 1M listeners. At the cost of writing each post 100K times (the average number of users on each channel).

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. That's helpful